# Crash MySQL cannot start mysql up

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a crash MySQL cannot start mysql up. Find out on the internet to fix it. Now I can start mysql but it reports the error of missing engine. I have tried all ways but can't fix the error of missing engine. If anyone has experience with fixing it or has a solution, please help me. I have attached the database and the error image.

Database: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyg8dchcm0wujl3/mysql.zip?dl=0
[image]

Comment: Error is self explanatory - "table doesn't exist", READ and follow the instructions are the bottom of the image.

Comment: So. How to fix @danblack ?

Comment: READ and follow the instructions are the bottom of the image